# CEP in apache beam with flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, apache-beam, complex-event-processing

We are using Apache beam to process events from various sources through Flink. We are in a situation where we need to use CEP engine of Flink to define event patterns and raise alerts.
I am not able to find any wrapper API in beam for this.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no Beam CEP available, there is [task](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3767) to create one, but I don't think there is currently much work done on this. I think if You need to use CEP, You will have to switch to Flink instead of Beam.